# Using multiple LINQ "Include" to get 2nd depth data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following model (simplified)

```
public partial class Fault
{
    public int FaultID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FaultComment> FaultComments { get; set; }
    public virtual User FaultCreatorUser { get; set; }
}

public partial class FaultComment
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int FaultID { get; set; }
    public string CommentContent { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CommentCreationDate { get; set; }
    public int CommentCreatorUserID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Fault Fault { get; set; }
}
```

So there is a fault.. it has a navigation property to get the collection of comments for a fault and each commend has a navigation property for the user that created the comment.

is it possible to create a LINQ statement that will retrieve the fault all of its comments and the users information for the comment ?

something like

```
var faultsWithComments = _context.Fault.Include("FaultComments").include("???FaultComments>>User???")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var faultsWithComments = _context.Fault.Include("FaultComments.User");
```

Or with EF >= 4.1 you can use a strongly typed version:

```
var faultsWithComments = _context.Fault
    .Include(f => f.FaultComments.Select(fc => fc.User));
```

(You need `using System.Data.Entity;` in your code file to have the `Include` extension method available that accepts a lambda expression as parameter.)

EF will include all related entities on the specified navigation path, so you don't need to include `FaultComments` explicitly when you include `FaultComments.User`.

Answer (score 0):

Functional VB.NET version of Slauma's answer:

```
var faultsWithComments = _context.Fault.Include(
   function (f) f.FaultComments.Select(
      function (fc) fc.User
   )
)
```